# Biztalk WCF-webhttp (WCF web publishing wizard)

Tags: biztalk

[I am new in biztalk trying to publish and consume servcie using webhttp (using Biztalk 2013, VS 2012)

getting following message and don't know want to do next to solve this issue.

**you have created a service.
To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. you can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:
svcutil.exe "http://[host]/expwebhttpsampledesktop/service1.svc?singlews"**dl

"svcutil.exe" command it generates .cs, .wsdl, and metadata.xml files for me.

not sure what i am doing wrong here but trying to consume the service i made. and at the end of it i am getting following error

"Error consuming WCF service metadata. Message part missing element. Correct service description ""http://tempuri.org/" message type "service1_operation1_inputmessage"" part "Part" and return the wizard."]

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a client that will now consume the service. A client can be anything from a simple Console app, a BizTalk Send Port, another Web-Service or a Winforms/WPF app. The client will invoke your service (possibly passing parameters), you service will do its stuff and return a response back to the client.

There are a number of ways to create a client, however you might want to start with this tutorial from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx.

Alternatively, you might want to search for 'Add Service Reference Visual Studio 2012'. Adding a service reference creates the necessary libraries for your client to consume the service.

UPDATE: I found some relevant screenshots, so I thought I would add them....

To add a Service Reference, right-click on your Project and select 'Add Service Reference':

[image: VS Add Service Reference Screenshot]

within the 'Add Service Reference' dialog, enter the address of the service (in your case *http://[host]/expwebhttpsampledesktop/service1.svc*) and click 'Go' for the wizard to auto-discover the service methods. Finally, update the service Namespace:

[image: VS Add Service Reference Dialog Screenshot]

You will now be able to reference your service just like any other type within C# in order to invoke it.

HTH, Nick.

Comment: Nick...Thank you very much for you reply. I have a question about it. when we use biztalk server web publishing wizard it is creating schema's and orchestration for us in iss aswell. in my case if i use web publishing wizard its creating schema's and orchestration too but when i use WCF webhttp it is creating .cs file and for metadata i am using svcutil.exe /t:metadata http://..... and it generates .wsdl file for me. is it suppose to be like that for i am missing any configuration in my system!!!

Comment: No that's fine, but you don't need to use the svcutil.exe tool - the Add Service Reference method mentioned in my answer replaces svcutil.exe (you would use svcutil.exe if you wanted finer grain control).